# apache reverseProxy how to proxypass to multi virtualhosts on same localhost and port?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, proxypass, mod-auth-openidc

I have an HTTPD apache reverse Proxy in a docker container on my PC. It manages also the authentication toward openidc sso.
Because I need to configure 3 different SSO on same host I configured 3 virtualHost in HTTPD.conf. I need that the first one redirect towards the 2 other depending on sub-route path. Here is my configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ${MON_IP_HOST}
    OIDCProviderMetadataURL http://SSO1…….
    <Location />
        #public
    </Location>
    <Location /api/SSO1/login>
        AuthType openid-connect
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /api/sso2/login  http://internal_sso2/api/sso2/login
    ProxyPassReverse /api/sso2/login  http://internal_sso2/api/sso2/login

    ProxyPass /api/sso3/login  http://sso3_local/api/sso3/login
    ProxyPassReverse /api/sso3/login  http://sso3_local/api/sso3/login

    #--- main proxy pass ---
    ProxyPass / ${banckendapiurl}
    ProxyPassReverse / ${banckendapiurl}  
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost internal_sso2:80>
    ServerName internal_sso2
    OIDCProviderMetadataURL http://SSO2 ……
    <Location />
        AuthType openid-connect
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / ${banckendapiurl}
   ProxyPassReverse / ${banckendapiurl}   
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost sso3_local:80>
    ServerName sso3_local
    OIDCProviderMetadataURL http://SSO3….
    <Location />
        AuthType openid-connect
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / ${banckendapiurl}
    ProxyPassReverse / ${banckendapiurl}   
</VirtualHost>
```

And the /etc/hosts file contains  :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost  sso3_local  internal_sso2
```

But when I call from a web browser the routes :
/api/sso2/login   or     api/sso3/login
They both forward to the second virualhost  only because it is defined in second position (if I place it in third position both call redirect toward sso3_local )

So what is wrong and how can I correctly prowypass internally to several virtual host ?

Comment: How you are accessing Apache httpd in browser ? i.e http://sso3_local///api/sso2/login and http://internal_sso2/api/sso3/login

Comment: by using  ${MON_IP_HOST} = my PC ip like 192....

Comment: You should access http://sso3_local/api/sso2/login

Comment: So what is wrong in my config ? all the redirection goes only to the second virtualhost, th third is ignored (same when I swich the order only the 2th works)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305001/all-requests-being-send-to-firstdefault-virtual-host  looks like similier to your issue

Comment: Apache tries to match the requests to a VirtualHost, checking them top down.  So if it does not match the first one (with IP), it will take the next one, hence your second VirtualHost.  That indicates that requests to http://internal_sso2 are not matched with your second VH.  Make sure you have defined the internal_sso2 and sso3_local names in your local host file.  Also increase your LogLevel in Apache, it will show you what it is doing, like which VH is uses and why (matches what).